# Domain controller stops mapping drives from file server

Tags: domain-controller, file-server, mappeddrive, shares, hard-drive

File Server:
Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Domain Controller:
Windows Server Standard FE 2003 SP2

This has happened twice now. User will try and log in using their domain accounts and will receive the black screen of death after hanging at the "mapping drives" stage at log in.

They will eventually get into their account but will not have access to the mapped drives from our file server. We have other servers that are still mapping properly. When logged into the file server itself I am sot able to reach the mapped drives that are shared out from the file server.
Rebooting the File Server fixes the problem, but we need to know why and how to prevent this from happening again.

Possible relevant information:
File server is running Eset antivirus.
A nightly windows server backup takes place at 10:00 p.m.
The symptoms were noticed both times in the mornings as users were fist arriving.
This has not occured again in the past 4 days.

Comment: It sounds like the file server is hanging and causing your logon script to hang, hence the symptoms you're seeing when logging on. I would focus on troubleshooting the file server. Look at CPU, Memory and Disk counters in perfmon.

Comment: I would like to first check disk usage, because during the first two occurrences i did not notice any significant usage in CPU or Memory. Could you recommend a tool to log disk usage?

Comment: I did, Performance Monitor (perfmon). Launch it and add counters from the physical disk object. - Start with %Disk Read Time, %Disk Write Time, %Disk Time, Avg. Disk Read Queue Length, Avg. Disk Write Queue Length, Avg. Disk Queue Length and Current Disk Queue Length.

Comment: What are the users logging on to?  The domain controller?  Their workstations (hopefully)?  It's not really clear what the domain controller's involvement in this process is, honestly.

Comment: The users are logging into their workstations using their domain accounts. I thought to include the domain controller in case there was a reason that the file server shares were not being mapped even though we have other servers that are properly mapping their shares using GPO's.